# What does the blocking option do in GRASS r.watershed?

Tags: grass-gis, grass-7.0

What does the `blocking` option do to the [r.watershed](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.watershed.html) program in grass? According to the manual, it should stop water from being routed past that location, but it appears to have no effect. I'm trying to determine if this is something I'm not understanding, or a bug in the program, but have not had luck with the grass mailing list (no replies at the time of this writing, [see thread here](https://www.mail-archive.com/grass-user@lists.osgeo.org/msg31665.html))